# EventBridge Input Transformer output nested attribute

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I'm attempting to configure AWS EventBridge to publish part of the event body to a Cloudwatch Logs Group. I believe what I'm trying to do matches the functionality of the option "Part of the Matched Event", but this option is invalid for the Cloudwatch Log Group target. Only the Input Transformation option is allowed for this target, and all attempts to output just a portion of the event have failed. It seems like there should be a way to get the value for a given JSONPath pattern (that is, the first value in the returned list).

The AWS docs [seem to indicate that you can refer to attributes whose value is an object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html#eb-transform-input-issues), as that mentions assigning `$.detail` to a variable and using it, which is essentially what I'm trying to do.

Sample event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "abc123",
  "detail-type": "Stuff",
  "source": "some place",
  "account": "12345",
  "time": "2023-03-01T17:48:02Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "data": {
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

Input path:

```
{"timestamp":"$.time", "data": "$.detail.data"}
```

Template:
`{"timestamp": <timestamp>, "message": <data>}`

I'd expect the output to be

```
{  "timestamp": 2023-03-01T17:48:02Z,
   "message": {
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   }
}
```

Instead, the output in the EventBridge console is

```
{"timestamp": 2023-03-01T17:48:02Z, "message": [object Object]}
```

And even worse, in the Cloudwatch Logs group the message is `{` and nothing else.

Surely I don't have to enumerate every possible attribute in the schema and set a variable for each, then include each in the template, right? That wouldn't be a problem with my sample event, but the real event I'm working with has a much more complicated schema.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify if anyone comes across this, this does work with Eventbridge rules delivering to Cloudwatch logs, but you do have to enumerate every individual variable and then reconstruct them in your "message" input template as a complex object.

Notes that would be helpful in AWS's documentation:

for the Input Template, `timestamp` needs to be in ISO format.  They don't clarify that anywhere (at least that I found).

`message` must be a `string`.  If properly formatted, Cloudwatch logs reconstructs it into a complex object, but it must be sent from the Eventbridge rule as a string.

For your example your Input Path would be:

`{"timestamp":"$.time", "value2": "$.detail.data.key2", "value3" : "$.detail.data.key3}`

And your input template would be:

```
{"timestamp": <timestamp>, 
"message": "{\"key2\":\"<value2>\",\"key3\":\"<value3>\"}"
}
```

It is annoying that it can't automatically parse out the more complex arguments into the `message` field, but if you do parse them all out and then reconstruct the complex object into a string, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing works.  The Configure input transformer tool shows [object object] output, which means it translated your patterns.  It's just not smart enough to display it fully.  When the event rule actually fires the object is sent to your target.  So, in your case your target would receive "message":{"key2":"value2","key3":"value3"} based on your sample.  Your will get what you are expecting short the "pretty" formatting.

Here's an example from what I use for my root account console login event:

> Input transformer
>
> Input path
>
> { "additional":"$.detail.additionalEventData",
>
> "arn": "$.detail.userIdentity.arn",
>
> "evTime": "$.detail.eventTime",
>
> "eventID": "$.detail.eventID",
>
> "response": "$.detail.responseElements",
>
> "sourceIP": "$.detail.sourceIPAddress"
> }
>
> Input template
>
> { "Alert!!!! Root console login at": ,
>
> "eventID": ,
>
> "arn": ,
>
> "successful": ,
>
> "sourceIP": ,
>
> "aboutSource": ,
>
> "Rule triggered": <aws.events.rule-name>,
>
> "event": <aws.events.event.json>
> }

Notice both  and  are nested objects. I send this to SNS to dispatch an email.  Here is the result minus the full event json for the last element (Xing out identifying information):

> { "Alert!!!! Root console login at": "2023-03-08T16:46:40Z",
>
> "eventID": "1df83625-8dd9-45ce-924e-4ab12436d481",
>
> "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:root",
>
> "successful": {"ConsoleLogin":"Success"},
>
> "sourceIP": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
>
> "aboutSource": {"LoginTo":"https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?hashArgs=%23&isauthcode=true&nc2=h_ct&src=header-signin&state=hashArgsFromTB_us-east-2_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","MobileVersion":"No","MFAIdentifier":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:mfa/XXXXXXXXX","MFAUsed":"Yes"},
>
> "Rule triggered": "Root-ConsoleLogin",
>
> "event":

Notice both "successful" and "aboutSource" are the resulting objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I actually get in the logs for the `message` portion is a single `{` and nothing else.

Comment: I noticed in your template you have <time>, but your input path has "timestamp":.  Wonder if your single { is due to <time> not being defined?

Comment: Good eye, there is a typo in my example. I did go back and check the actual template I was testing in AWS and I'm using the correct variable name in that. I'll update my question though. Thanks.

Comment: I added an example to my answer as I am utilizing the same sort of thing for my root account console login notice.  Where I am sending the event to SNS to dispatch an email.  
Could your issue be with your target receiving correctly, rather than how CloudWatch is sending the event alert?  What is your target method?

Comment: It may be that the problem is with the target, a Cloudwatch Logs group. I haven't tried any other targets because the only thing I want is to dump this JSON in logs. AWS Support suggested using a Lambda target and writing a function to format the message and then publish to Cloudwatch Logs, but I shouldn't have to pay for a massive number of Lambda invocations to work around a deficiency in EventBridge/Cloudwatch Logs integration.

Comment: The EventBridge service team confirmed via AWS Support that this isn't supported for Cloudwatch Log Group targets, and that a user will need to stick a Lambda in between to reformat the message in this way. Disappointing, but not surprising.