# JSONPath to reference json inside of json

Tags: json, jsonpath, aws-event-bridge

This is on AWS Eventbridge input transformer, AWS UI not code

So i have a JSON

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "437e4ed4-8ee1a178",
  "detail-type": "blah",
  "source": "blahblah",
  "account": "011604459942",
  "time": "2023-11-20T23:20:14Z",
  "detail": {
    "transaction_id": 6787,
    "customer_id": 1234,
   ...
    "created_at": "2023-11-21T10:19:40.929+11:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-11-21T10:19:52.425+11:00"
  }
}
```

and inside that json i have the detail json, i want to reference it with JSONPath to reference but i am failing

**Input path**

```
{
  "detail": "$.detail"
}
```

**Template**

```
{  
"document": <detail>
}
```

**result**

```
{
  "document": [object Object]

}
```

How do i get all the values in detail and not [Object object]? i need to do this cause whats in detail changes per request so i cant list all the values

Comment: where do i put that?

Comment: Answer to question can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75609162/eventbridge-input-transformer-output-nested-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You must add all fields you need from detail to the path:

```
 {
   "transaction_id": "$.detail.transaction_id",
   "customer_id": "$.detail.customer_id",
   "created_at": "$.detail.created_at",
   "updated_at": "$.detail.updated_at"
 }
```

Also, update your template:

```
 {  
  "document": "{ \"transaction_id\": \"<transaction_id>\", \"customer_id\": \"<customer_id>\", \"created_at\": \"<created_at>\", \"updated_at\": \"<updated_at>\" }"
 }
```

Comment: The details document changes constantly is there a way i can do this without manually adding all of them in?